# Remove Web Element from WebPage With Selenium

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, http

Starting say that i know it's a bad practice to remove WebElement from a WebPage.

For testing purpose, i want understand if i can 'modify' the web page i load 'in local (so client side)' on my webBrowser, using Selenium automation.

In this example, i want to load the 'Google' main page, and try to remove the 'Google' title, from my webBrowser.

I tried using JavaScriptExecutor, but fail.

Here is the code.

```
Dim driver As IWebDriver
Dim ChromeOptions As New ChromeOptions
Dim driverWait_5 As Support.UI.WebDriverWait
Dim jsExec As OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    driver = New ChromeDriver("C:\ChromeDriver", ChromeOptions)
    driverWait_5 = New Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    jsExec = CType(driver, OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor)
    Dim address As String = "https://www.google.co.uk/webhp"
    driver.Navigate.GoToUrl(address)
    Dim element As IWebElement = driverWait_5.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("lga")))
    If IsNothing(element) = False Then
        jsExec.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('lga').remove();")
    End If

End Sub
```

Any help?

Updated, after help of @Infern0 and @ali, i updated the code, that now works.
Thanks all.

Comment: your approach seems legit. do you have an error executing the code ? p.s. try to execute "return document.getElementById('lga').remove();"

Comment: @Infern0, thanks, on a Try-Catch block, Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Infern0 Sorry i forget an instruction (jsExec = CType(driver, OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor)), now the code runs without exception, but in 'Chrome' browser the 'google' title it's still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Vb.Net syntax but the C# version below should work;

```
private void RemoveGoogleLogo()
{
    var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"<<chromePath>>")
    {
        Url = "https://www.google.co.uk/webhp"
    };
    driver.Navigate();

    var driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    driverWait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("lga")).Displayed);
    driver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('lga').remove();");
}
```

Comment: Thanks ali, in the javascript code, i forget '()' after .remove